# iOS 11.3 beta 4 safari crashing when using H4 tags

Tags: html, ios, ionic-framework, safari, ionic3

Getting this weird issue on my Ionic app where when I use H4 tags, the app will crash. This only happens on iOS 11.3 Beta 4, all non-beta versions don't break. There are no errors or anything except

```
WebCore::RenderTreeUpdater::createRenderer(WebCore::Element&, WebCore::RenderSTyle&&)
```

The above error only shows when running the app from XCode, no where else.

Makes no sense to my why an H4 tag would be crashing the app.